# Execute system commands using wmi python on remote computer

Tags: python, windows, wmi

I am trying to create a directory on a remote computer using wmi and python. I am able to successfully run any batch file by providing the complete path to it. But not execute system command.

This following code does not create a directory on the remote computer.

```
conn = wmi.WMI('172.20.23.45', user='Administrator', password='Pass@123')
conn.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine='mkdir temp')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done as.

```
conn.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine='cmd.exe /c mkdir temp')
```

Comment: what does /c do?  Thanks.

Comment: /C - Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates.    For more info "cmd.exe /?"

Comment: @Rahul You can redirect to a file and then read from that. ex: ls > output.txt

Comment: @reply Redirect it to a file and then read from it.